# Sbt eviciting libraries after migration to Play 2.5.2

Tags: playframework

I have just migrated my project to Play 2.5.2 (from 2.4.6). However, when I do run sbt update I got the following warnings :

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-cache_2.11:2.4.6 -> 2.5.2
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-ws_2.11:2.4.6 -> 2.5.2
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-netty-server_2.11:2.4.6 -> 2.5.2
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-server_2.11:2.4.6 -> 2.5.2
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.11:1.0.0 -> 1.1.1
```

I am not sure what should I do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a dependency (e.g. in your `build.sbt`) which explicitly depends on Play 2.4.6. You could try commenting out other dependencies to figure out which one causes this problem.

I had the same issue which, I believe, was caused by an older version of `play2-reactivemongo`.